# facebbok js sdk login function not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My facebook login doesn't work. It open the popup ask me a permission. I allow permission then  it stuck on the blank popup and give me js error.

```
error in event handler for (unknown): Error: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': The provided node was null.
at observeNodes (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/jslib/Rain1/Overlay.js:216:13)
at init (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/version2.js:218:6)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/version2.js:55:3)
at c (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:7857)
at Object.p.add [as done] (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:8167)
at b.fn.b.ready (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:2072)
at b.fn.b.init (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:1602)
at b (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:206)
at Object.fetchAll0 (chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/version2.js:54:2)
at chrome-extension://ihamlfilbdodiokndlfmmlpjlnopaobi/jslib/Rain1/Overlay.js:125:51
```

Here is my code.

```
 <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxx',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));

   //LOGIN FUNCTION 
   function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            alert('Success!');
        }
        console.log(response);
    }, {scope: 'email'});
 }
  </script>
  <div onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
</body>
```

Anyone have an idea about it?

PS. I tested share/login in my old apps. They are broken too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's facebook api servers fault, is down!

I was working normal and minutes ago the javascript sdk stop working and stuck with a blank popup as you describe.

I was able to connect normally by PHP sdk but not with javascript sdk.

hope this helps and little.

Comment: check the official FB response about it: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/482108261888889/